# Reading CSV file in Python, Getting the column (Average)

Tags: python, csv

How do you read each line in a csv file and average it per column?

CSV File will look like this

```
15 1 2 3
30 5 12 5
40 2 3 10
```

The result should be the average of the column

```
28.33
2.67
5.66
6
```

Something like that

I tried so many workarounds but I cant seem to get it to work

```
import csv


with open(test_file, "r") as input_file:
  reader = csv.reader(input_file)

for row in reader:
  print(row[0])

total = 0
avg = 0
for num in row:
  print(row[0][num])
  total += int(num)
  avg = total/len(num)


print(avg)
print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the whole file as lines into a list, split each line, use `zip()` to transform it and calculate your averages.

You read each line, split it and convert it to a number, add it into a dictionary with the columnindex as key and afterwards calculate the average.

```
with open("n.txt", "w") as w:
    w.write('15 1 2 3\n30 5 12 5\n40 2 3 10')

l = []
nums_per_line = 0
with open("n.txt") as w:
    for line in w:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            l.append(list(map(float, line.split())))

for t in zip(*l):
    print(sum(t)/len(t))
```

or:

```
d = {}
nums_per_line = 0
with open("n.txt") as w:
    for line in w:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            nums_per_line = len(l) # all lines need to have the same amount of numbers!
            for i,v in enumerate(l[-1]):
                d.setdefault(i,0)
                d[i] += v

for k in d:
    print(d[k]/nums_per_line)
```

Output:

```
28.333333333333332
2.6666666666666665
5.666666666666667
6.0

28.333333333333332
2.6666666666666665
5.666666666666667
6.0
```

You can limit the output using `print(round( ..... , 2))`

The `zip(*l)` does the following:

```
# the list l:
[[15.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [30.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0], [40.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0]]

# list(zip(*l)) is it transposed:
[(15.0, 30.0, 40.0), (1.0, 5.0, 2.0), (2.0, 12.0, 3.0), (3.0, 5.0, 10.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=','(or ';'), headers=0 (if no headers))
df.mean(axis=0)
```

Gives the following as output :

```
0    28.333333
1     2.666667
2     5.666667
3     6.000000
```

Comment: Probably add something like `[print(x) for x in df.iloc(:, 0).tolist()]`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a simple function to return your columns from the CSV file,
the function by default converts to floating point numbers, but it can be whatever conversion, and if you have non-homogeneous data you can use a list of conversion functions — the optional keyword arguments are passed to `csv.reader`.

```
def read_convert_csv(iterable, headers=False, conv=float, **kw):
    from csv import reader
    from itertools import repeat

    try: conv[0] # if conv is a list or a tuple, do not touch it 
    except TypeError: conv = repeat(conv)

    data = reader(iterable, **kw)
    if headers: headers = next(data)
    cols = zip(*((c(item)for item, c in zip(row, conv)) for row in data))
    return {h:c for h,c in zip(headers, cols)} if headers else list(cols)
```

By default the function returns a list of columns, if you specify `headers=True` the first line of CSV is interpreted as headers and a dictionary of columns keyed by the corresponding headers is returned instead.

Next, you use the function on your data (note that we need to pass `delimiter=' '`) to the CSV reader)

```
cols = read_convert_csv(open('my_data.csv', 'r'), delimiter=' ')
```

Eventually, you compute the means

```
means = [sum(col)/len(col) for col in cols]
```